# How to change values of 'title' and 'description' with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
newList.addItem({
title: 'London',
description: 'Capital of GB'
});
```

I need to change these values clicking on some div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) like,

```
$(function(){
    newList='#idList';
    $('div').on('click',function(){
        $(newList).attr({
           title: 'London',
           description: 'Capital of GB'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well use this:

```
$('div').click(function () { // on the click
   // change the values here :/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#idofyourdiv').click(function() {
    // Do whatever you want with that object
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('div_selector').click(function (){ 
$(newList).attr({title: 'New title',description: 'newdescrption'});
}
```